# Encrypting then Base64 Encoding

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I notice online encryption tools encrypt the plaintext and output the ciphertext in  base64 format. Why is ciphertext outputted in base64 format? Can the ciphertext be outputted in binary format?

Comment: You can translate that data into *any* base, it just happens that Base64 is well suited for the web; it's composed of characters that are safe to use in URLs.

Comment: it avoids issue with special, reserved, and control characters, allowing the ciphertext to use all 255 combos per byte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ciphertext can be output in binary format.  For example, gpg defaults to binary format, and you [need to specify `--armor`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg2) to make it base64:

```
--armor
-a
    Create ASCII armored output. The default is to create the binary OpenPGP format.
```

The reason you see ASCII/base64 more often is that it is easier to transfer and manipulate than binary.  SMTP email, for example, cannot handle binary data without encoding it, so having a non-binary format makes it simpler to email encrypted text.  FTP may default to non-binary mode which will introduce errors when transferring a binary file.  Even something as simple as popping open a file in an editor to make sure it "looks like it's there" is easier with non-binary formats.

Answer (score 3):

A web browser has to print a visual representation of the binary data. The usual visual representation of binary data is the hexadecimal notation.

Now observe: The space overhead of hex-encoded data is factor 2 (we need 2 ascii characters for one byte).
The space overhead of base64-encoded data is only 1.33, making it more space-efficient than hex-encoded data.

Moreover, I suspect that the tool support for base64-encoded data is at least as good as for hex-encoded data.

For instance, you can copy-paste a base64-encoded ciphertext directly into a PEM file.